# How to download images saved on the DB in html

Tags: html

My code is basically this... If there was a functionality like "controls" for video tag, would be awesome, but there isn't. I do not know to mae a button or icon, etc, to download the image. I also tried `<a href="" download> Download Link </a>`, but it does not work because the image is not static on a file, but dynamically saved on the DB.
I just need a download button/icon to download the actual image being displayed.

```
          <!-- album starts -->
             
          <div class="full-img" id="fullImgBox">

              <img src="images/img1.jpg" id="fullImg" controls class="media">
              <span class="material-icons" onclick="closeFullImg()">close</span>
          </div>
          <div class="img-gallery">
          <?php if(count($posts) !== 0) { ?>

              <?php foreach($posts as $post) { 
                if( $post['post_type'] == "image"){
              ?>
                <img src="<?= POSTS_SAVED_TO.$post['uploaded_file_name'] ?>" onclick="openFullImg(this.src)"/>
              <?php
                }
              } 
           } else { ?> 
          <p class="alert alert-info">No Posts are made yet !!.</p>
          <?php } ?>
          </div>

          <script>

              var fullImgBox = document.getElementById("fullImgBox");
              var fullImg = document.getElementById("fullImg");

              function openFullImg(pic) {
                  fullImgBox.style.display = "flex";
                  fullImg.src = pic;
              }

              function closeFullImg() {
                  fullImgBox.style.display = "none";
              }

          </script>
```

Comment: I do not want to use right-click button options...

Comment: This might help https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_download_link

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your image is on the same domain as your script you can use the `download` attribute on an anchor:

```
<a href="<?= POSTS_SAVED_TO.$post['uploaded_file_name'] ?>" download="myfile">
    <img src="<?= POSTS_SAVED_TO.$post['uploaded_file_name'] ?>" />
</a>
```

The `myfile` property of the download attribute will be the name of the downloaded file, and the extension will be set automatically.